# Could not find a 'develop' or 'master' branch, neither locally nor remotely. - Semantic gitversion

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, semantic-versioning, gitversion

I have a repo in azure and it has the default branch "main".

Also, I have a task in yml file for semantic versioning.

```
- task: gittools.gitversion.gitversion-task.GitVersion@5
  displayName: Get Semantic Git Version
```

I am hitting the below error

> No branch configuration found for branch personal/release1, falling
> back to default configuration System.InvalidOperationException: Could
> not find a 'develop' or 'master' branch, neither locally nor remotely.

So, I just created a develop branch and triggered build then the semantic version got succeeded.

We do not want to maintain develop or master branch as per guidelines.

How can we overcome the error without maintaining the master and develop branch?

Thanks

Naresh Ede

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check about below workarounds with GitTools extension. How did it go?

Comment: Hi Levi, gitversion.yml worked for me. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @Naresh Ede - is it working for you even after deleting the develop branch? 
i have the same issue - we don't use a develop branch,
i added the GitVersion.yml config file, but the issue persists, and i dont want to create a develop branch just to overcome this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks that this is not supported yet by [GitTools\GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2433) and it is still waiting for a solution.

But to overcome this you can provide GitVersion.yml file

```yaml
mode: ContinuousDelivery
branches:
  master:
    regex: main
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag:
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
  feature:
    regex: feature(s)?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
  develop:
    regex: dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: alpha
  hotfix:
    regex: hotfix(es)?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: beta
  release:
    regex: release(s)?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: rc
ignore:
  sha: []
```

And then use it like this

```yaml
steps:
- task: GitVersion@5
  inputs:
    runtime: 'core'
    configFilePath: 'GitVersion.yml'
    updateAssemblyInfo: true
```

Comment: is this solution possible also without having develop branch at all? 
we don't have and we don't want to create develop branch just to overcome this error.

Answer (score 3):

[GitVersion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) task is deprecated.  It uses the an old version(5.0.1) of GitVersion, which caused above error. It is recommended to use [GitTools bundle extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gittools) instead. You can install GitTools extension in your project. See below example;

```
- task: gitversion/setup@0
  displayName: Install GitVersion
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'
 
- task: gitversion/execute@0
```

Please check the [document](https://github.com/GitTools/actions/blob/master/docs/examples/azure/gitversion/index.md) for more usages.

You can also use [UseGitVersion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.usegitversion&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) task. And use the latest 5 version by specifying the `versionSpec`.

```
- task: UseGitVersion@5
  displayName: gitversion
  inputs: 
   versionSpec: 5.x
  enabled: true
```

Or you can use a GitVersion.yml config file as Krzysztof Madej mentioned to map the main branch to master branch.

```
mode: ContinuousDelivery
branches:
  master:
    regex: main
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
```