# GitVersion tool fails over develop branch does not exist

Tags: git, build, azure-pipelines, semantic-versioning, gitversion

We want to integrate GitVersion in our build pipeline for semantic versioning.

We are seeing the following error on a repo which doesn't have develop branch:

> ERROR [06/07/22 16:04:53:53] An unexpected error occurred:
> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a 'develop' or
> 'master' branch, neither locally nor remotely. at
> GitVersion.Configuration.BranchConfigurationCalculator.InheritBranchConfiguration(Branch
> targetBranch, BranchConfig branchConfiguration, Commit currentCommit,
> Config configuration, IList`1 excludedInheritBranches) in
> D:\a\GitVersion\GitVersion\src\GitVersionCore\Configuration\BranchConfigurationCalculator.cs:line
> 62

I tried to add the gitVersion.yml config file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610829/could-not-find-a-develop-or-master-branch-neither-locally-nor-remotely-s) - but it didn't help.

Is there a way to overcome this issue without creating develop branch? we don't want to maintain a branch just to overcome this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the other answer, did you change this part to whatever your branch name is: "master: regex: **main**" ?

Comment: yes, my regex is: (master|main) and I'm working with master.
Anyways, the issue is with develop branch which i don't have and don't want to create and maintain just to overcome this error.

Comment: I confess I know nothing about gitversion, but the way I interpret the error is that it can't find your `master` branch either. I get the impression it's looking for either `develop` or `master`, and if just one of them existed, it would be OK with it, but it can't find either of them, thus the error. (Obviously I could be wrong, but that would be a strange way to word the error message if it found `master` but not `develop`, and it needed both.)

Comment: Yes, it’s sounds logical. 
And the strange thing it worked before on this repo.